# Ubuntu Server booting with NGINX running and not Apache2

Tags: 14.04, package-management, nginx

I am running a server with Ubuntu Server 14.04.  When I reboot the server it boots up with `nginx` running, and not `apache2` like I would like.

I end up having to stop the `nginx` service, then restart `apache2` to get everything running as I would like it to.

To further complicate my problem is when I try to remove `nginx` it says it is not installed but if I run `locate nginx` it brings up a couple hundred files so clearly it is installed.

How do I remove `nginx` completely?  I've tried removing and purging the `nginx` package without success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `nginx` package is just a metapackage, and points to the nginx flavors.  Because `apt-get`, `apt`, and `dpkg` are not as smart as users assume it will be, removing the `nginx` package does ***not*** remove the actual `nginx` binaries and common files.

Run the following to remove all flavors of NGINX from the system.  This will catch at least one installed one, and the common files that are common across the entire set:

```
sudo apt-get remove nginx nginx-common nginx-full nginx-extras nginx-core nginx-naxsi nginx-light nginx-doc
```

After this, you can then run Apache automatically.

**NOTE:** Ubuntu Server does not come with `nginx` automatically installed - when you install a web server on Ubuntu Server via `tasksel` or as a LAMP install, you get Apache, and not `nginx`.  You will not be able to run `nginx` if you are running `apache2`, unless you change the nginx configurations to move the nginx default to a separate port.

Comment: Note that I help maintain the `nginx` package, so I'm VERY familiar with this issue cropping up.

Comment: I will try this now, in regards to your note I had no problems until I installed webmin

Comment: @ChrisJamesChampeau if you did that, webmin is set up to use Apache only, in its binaries.  That always causes a problem, as webmin isn't just PHP, and is a whole other issue.  That, and webmin works with Apache more than it does nginx.  HOwever, the above instructions will nuke nginx completely.  It will not remove the configuration files but it will remove the binaries.

Comment: Ok I ran it and am trying the reboot now

Comment: @ChrisJamesChampeau You're welcome.  Next time, might I recommend not using the `nginx` package but rather, say, the `nginx-full` package instead if you're setting up nginx?  It'll still isntall the binaries, but it'll be a more full core featureset, and will not cause the confusion you've seen before.